# Are Sqlite Insert , Delete, Synchronous in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

In my android application , i am doing SQlite DB operations like insert, delete, update records.
i want to know , if i do like below:

```
long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
for(i =0; i<N; i++)
{
  insertRecord();
}
long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

does t2-t1 will equal the time taken to insert N records in DB. 
I mean is the call to insert synchronous or asynchronous.

Comment: they are synchronous!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are inside a transaction, the data will be actually written and synchronized only when the transaction ends.

If you are not using explicit transactions, everything happens inside the `insert()` call, and you will indeed measure what you want.
However, such operations are run with an implicit transaction, which makes them rather slow (because the synchronization overhead is there for every command).

When you're doing several related database operations, you should put all of them into a single transaction:

```
long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

db.beginTransaction();
try {
    for(i =0; i<N; i++) {
        insertRecord();
    }
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}

long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Comment: Inside InsertRecord(), i query to DB for all records. Then do some calculations . And based on those calulation , i insert the record to DB.

So when finally block executes this mean , everything is written to DB ,right ?

Comment: It's possible that the DB runs out of memory earlier, and needs to write something. However, only after the end of the transaction is it *guaranteed* that everything is written.

Answer (score 1):

if you are calling these CRUD methods from multiple places , it is better to make these methods Synchronized to avoid locking and getting exception.

Answer (score 0):

this is synchronous insert because it insert one after the other in other hand should execute first insert to execute the second one

you also can use AsyncTask to solve Insert Speed Problem